# Testing contrib.messages from an UpdateView with pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest

I'm testing an update view with **pytest**. The following test runs ok. The `lang_src` instance is correctly updated.

```py
class TestAvailableUpdateView:
    url = "dashboard.staff:available-update"

    def test_authenticated_staff(self, staff_client, lang_src):
        url = reverse(self.url, kwargs={'pk': lang_src.pk})
        data = {'code': 'it', 'pk': lang_src.pk}
        resp = staff_client.post(url, data=data)
        assert resp.status_code == 302
        lang_src.refresh_from_db()
        assert lang_src.code == 'it'
```

`staff_client` is defined in `factories.py`:

```py
from django.test import Client

@pytest.fixture()
def staff_user(db):
    return User.objects.create_user(
        username='staff@example.com',
        password='password', is_staff=True,
        is_active=True)


@pytest.fixture()
def staff_client(staff_user):
    """Return a Django test client logged in as a staff user."""
    client = Client()
    client.login(username=staff_user.username, password='password')
    return client
```

To test `messages` from `contrib.messages`, I've setup `folllow=True` as following.

```py
    def test_updated_message(self, staff_client, lang_src):
        url = reverse(self.url, kwargs={'pk': lang_src.pk})
        data = {'code': 'it', 'pk': lang_src.pk}
        resp = staff_client.post(url, data=data, follow=True)
        assert resp.status_code == 200
        message = list(resp.context.get('messages'))[0]
        assert message == 'Languages updated'
```

I'm returned a `TemplateResponse` where `resp.context['messages']` doesn't contain any message.

Here is the view:

```py
class AvailableLanguageUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = AvailableLanguage
    template_name = "dashboard_staff/languages/lang_form.html"
    extra_context = {"available_lang_menu": True}
    fields = ['code']
    success_msg = _("Languages updated")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_msg)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And the model has a `get_absolute_url()` method that redirects to a listview which works fine. And I must say that the update works fine too.

**3rd EDIT**

When I run test, I got these exceptions:

> AssertionError: assert <django.contrib.messages.storage.base.Message object at 0x7f56f02c0dd8> == 'Languages updated'

And if I test the `resp.url`, the exception is:

> AttributeError: 'TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'url'

The `resp` is:

`<TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: What does the view for `dashboard.staff:available-update` look like? And if it's the response after the redirect that is causing you trouble, what does the view you redirect to look like?

Comment: @Alasdair I added the view to my post.

Comment: What is the view that you expect the request to be redirected to? What is the result of `resp = staff_client.post(...)`? If you're getting an exception, then please show the full exception.

Comment: It's not related to translations. I removed the Ajaxable mixin and override the form_valid method but I still get a ```templateResponse```. If I print the ```resp.content```, I got the listview pages as expected but with only one object in ```object_list```, the one that has been updated, which is pretty normal as we are in test mode.

Comment: @Alasdair I found how to get the message ! That's weird to me but it works ! ```[m.message for m in get_messages(resp.wsgi_request)]``` Many thanks for your attention !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution worth to be mentioned because many solutions using `response.context.get('messages')` doesn't work.

I found out that `messages` are stored in `wsgi_request`. So, in order to test your `success_message` you could do something like:

```py
class TestAvailableUpdateView:
    url = "dashboard.staff:available-update"

    def test_updated_message(self, staff_client, lang_src):
        url = reverse(self.url, kwargs={'pk': lang_src.pk})
        data = {'code': 'it', 'pk': lang_src.pk}
        resp = staff_client.post(url, data=data, follow=True)
        assert resp.status_code == 200
        messages = [m.message for m in get_messages(resp.wsgi_request)]
        assert 'Languages updated' in messages
```